# How make localized messages display correcty?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am using default PostgreSQL install on Windows XP. Unfortunately localized (non-english) messages are not displayed correctly neither in SQL Shell nor in diagnostic messages during app run-time.

What can be done to make Postgre show messages correctly?

Sample message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'value';` is a typical solution. Please, read [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/multibyte.html) for more.

Comment: Also note that in both cases your terminal (or whatever your app display is) needs to support the encoding you specify.